# How to perform queries via SqlKata?

Tags: .net-core, ado.net, sqlkata

I'm using **SqlKata** to perform db queries.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```cs
var task1= GetData(id);
var task2 = HasPrivilege(Id);
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
var data = await task1;
var hasPrivilege = await task2;
```

But I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: BeginExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection

I've registered SqlKata's `QueryFactory` as below:

```cs
services.AddTransient(provider =>
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    var compiler = new SqlServerCompiler();
    var queryFactory = new QueryFactory(connection, compiler);
    queryFactory.Logger = compiled => Console.WriteLine(compiled.ToString());
    return queryFactory;
});
```

Comment: Please share with us the `GetData` and `HasPrivilege` methods' implementation as well.

Comment: The error is clear - the connection is closed. You need to call `connection.Open()`. Apart from that, there's no code that shows how the query factory is used.